# Recovery disk Windows 8 HP Pavilion g6

Tags: windows

I recently purchased a HP Pavilion g6 laptop running Windows 8. I want to either obtain the Windows 8 ISO or make some kind of recovery disk that would allow me to restore the system if things go wrong.

The HP Pavilion comes with the 'HP Recovery Manager' which I thought may do the job, but on running it and putting in a DVD-R as requested it seems to just hang for a number of hours without doing a thing (the disk sounds like it's spinning for a few minutes but then goes silent).

I then tried 'recdisc.exe' but I get the error

```
System Repair could not be created
The device reported unexpected or invalid data for a command. (0xC0AA02FF)
```

Next I obtained my Windows 8 product key using the software `ProduKey` thinking this would allow me to go to the Microsoft website and download the Windows 8 ISO, but as far as I can tell all that is available is the upgrade which can be used if one is running something like Windows 7.

Can anyone advise?

EDIT: after a reboot recdisc.exe did work; I think the problem was due to some Windows updates needing a reboot, but never the less  I would like a full Windows 8 ISO if possible.

Comment: If you solved the problem, instead of editing the question, make it an answer and mark it as such after the time limit

Comment: Not really solved the problem- I still would like to create a Windows 8 installation disk from ISO using my product key and/or work out how to create a full recovery disk (e.g. using the HP Recovery Manager say). I think all `recdisc.exe` has given me is a few recovery tools.

Comment: Then that information is what you should put in the question. As it stands now, after your first edit, it looks like you are just looking for a location for the Windows 8 ISO; is that correct?

Comment: @Luke after the edit I believe it reads that I am after the location of the Windows 8 ISO (not just the upgrade from Windows 7, but the ISO for someone who has bought a new laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed and has a Windows 8 product key etc etc). Also as the OP mentions I'm having issues with the HP recovery manager. So 2 of 3 of the original points remain.

Comment: I know you paid for the laptop and OS, but the original unaltered ISO sans crapware is not available to you for free; you'll need to buy a copy of Windows 8. Laptop manufacturers long ago stopped bundling Windows DVDs, and even recovery DVDs.

Comment: @Karan, thanks. Crazy, so basically the only option available to new laptop owners is to create some recovery disks (i.e. via something like the HP Recovery manager , if only it would work...), then presumably this would recover the laptop to its post-purchase state.

Comment: Yes, or many laptops have a separate recovery partition taking up 10-20+ GB of your hard disk's space. Pressing some special recovery key or sequence during bootup will make the machine go into recovery mode, wipe the system partition and reinstall the OS along with all the bundled crapware from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Call Up HP support and tell them the problem and ask them to send you Windows 8 OEM DVD.

I had a Dell laptop and the same thing was happening with me. When I called them up and told about the problem they shipped me a OEM DVD.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In my case the reason was that Windows 8 does not have built in CD/DVD burning software. Well, some operations can be performed but some functions are missing. For example, there is no 'erase disc' option for DVD drive in the context menu of Windows 8 file explorer. This option presented however in Windows 7. So, I simply installed free CD/DVD burning software [InfraRecorder](http://www.infrarecorder.org) and the problem was solved. I mean that after this procedure Windows 8 created recovery disk without any error messages. I also suspect that any other CD/DVD burning software would solve the problem, but I didn't check it. Good luck!